Linear probability model: Interpretation of a logged discrete/count variable
Based on this SO question, I have a question about the interpretation of linear-log models when the logged variable is categorical.
If my model is $y = b_0 + b_1\times \log(x_1)$, where $y$ is categorical, log is the natural logarithm and $x_1$ is continuous, then an 1% increase in $x_1$ changes the probability of $y$ by $\frac{b_1}{100}$ percentage points and a 10% increase in $x_1$ changes $y$ by $b_1\log(1.10)$ percentage points.
However, if $x_1$ is discrete, i.e. number of children or number of times being fired, then  knowing how an 1% increase in $x_1$ changes the probability of $y$ is less realistic, important or informative than knowing how adding a child or being fired once more increases the probability of $y$. How would I calculate the probability for this case?

How do you take the logarithm of a categorical variable?

Thank you, I changed categorical to discrete.

And if that discrete variable takes zero, as they often do?

Very true, I would do ln(x1+1).

But then you aren’t logging your variable.

I do not understand where you are trying to lead me.


$\ln(x_1+1)$ is not taking logs of $x_1$. I believe this is Dave's point. 2. Your title and first paragraph refer to a categorical variable; is that $y$ you're referring to there or should those mentions of categorical variables also be changed to discrete variable (indeed, probably to count variable, since it's the possibility of $0$ that leads to issues). 3. Is $y$ binary (0/1)? 4. I suggest trying searches; there are a number of questions on site about logs of shifted count variables, some of which may be relevant.


Thank you @Glen_b. I've corrected the title and will search with the information you provided. Thank you for the help.
